# 3d button with click effect

Tags: android, button, click, effect

I'm trying to create a flat button with a 3D effect that depresses when you click it
[image: flatbutton]

I have styled a clickable textview with a selector that shows an unpressed version and a pressed version. The trouble is I don't know how to get the text to appear to move in the same way the background does i.e. it should look like a physical key being pushed down so the text moves down a bit when it's pressed and returns when it's released. Here's my code.

TextView/button I want to style:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chip_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="@color/speedDialText"
    android:background="@drawable/chip_view_selector"
/>
```

chip_view_selector.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false">
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_view_shadow" android:top="4dp"/>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_view_btn_face" android:bottom="4dp"/>
            </layer-list>
        </item>

        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_view_shadow" android:top="4dp"/>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/chip_view_btn_face" android:top="4dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
            </layer-list>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

chip_view_btn_face.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <!-- Button foreground -->
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/speedDialButtonBackground" />
        <padding
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

chip_view_shadow.xml (it's not really the shadow but the underneath layer that gives it a 3d look):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <!-- 3d effect part of button (not the button face) -->
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#D3D3D3" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Class named : VariableGravityButton as follows :

```
public class VariableGravityButton extends Button {
public VariableGravityButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VariableGravityButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public VariableGravityButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    if (pressed != isPressed()) {
        setGravity(pressed ? Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL |
                Gravity.BOTTOM : Gravity.CENTER);
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}}
```

Sometimes, extend Buttons - may give error, Dont Afraid, just keep going. Then uses the button: Your Packagename + the above Class name,  as follows:

```
<android.learning.learning.VariableGravityButton
android:id="@+id/chip_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/speedDialText"
android:background="@drawable/chip_view_selector"/>
```

This button text will jump to the bottom when it is pressed.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this post is so old I moved onto working on other things but I will definitely come back and give this a try when I get the chance.  I don't think this will work exactly as desired (as the button effectively has 3 layers, and only the top 2 should move) but it's given me a good idea about how to implement it

Comment: I have tested personally with your code applying this, and its worked fine with a button.